# Plot3d only plots first two principle components

Tags: r, pca

I am currently trying to plot the colours of different subgroups of a large dataset. I have separated the data in to 6 subgroups with 6 colours. However my plot3d function only plots the first two principle components. 
Here is the example of the plot.
[image]
Here is the code. I have create a PCA analysis of my dataset and originally only want to show the first 3 main principle components but I have tried plotting all the principle components to ensure it isn't to do with the data.

```
PCA_Model <- prcomp(t(Input_dataset), center = T, scale=F)
samples_names <- row.names(PCA_Model$rotation)
# Bind sample names to their subgroup
pca_matrix <- cbind(samples_names, "Subgroup"=labeled_subgroup, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# Link dataframe to color
colours <- as.character(factor(pca_matrix[,"Subgroup"], levels = paste0("C", 1:6),labels = c("blue", 
"red", "yellow", "green", "black", "white")))
plot3d(PCA_Model$x[,1:440], col=colours)
```

The dataset is very diverse so should show all subgroups. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You may be using the wrong plotting function. Using `scatter3d` in the latest version of `plot3D` package:

```
# fit PCA model
PCA_Model <- prcomp(dplyr::select(iris, -Species), center = T, scale=F)
# Plot
scatter3D(x = PCA_Model$x[,1], y = PCA_Model$x[,2], z = PCA_Model$x[,3], 
          # just use the factor to color the points:
          col = factor(iris$Species))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you get something odd from feeding characters into the col option of plot3d. So below I show an example of how to feed the colors. You create a color vector first, named it after your levels and then call them out. Adjust the script before for 6 colours:

```
  library(rgl)
    library(RColorBrewer)
    pca = prcomp(iris[,-5])$x
    COLS = brewer.pal(3,"Set1")
    names(COLS) = levels(iris$Species)
    plot3d(pca,col=COLS[as.character(iris$Species)])
```

I used `snapshot3d()` to capture the image, and the axis labels seem quite squished

[image]